# mysqli connection - How to create username and password? windows server 2008

Tags: php, mysql, windows, mysqli

I am trying to incorporate mysql with a mobile app.

I just added the mySQLi php extension to my windows server 2008, but cannot figure out how to connect with the php code:
           $this->db = new mysqli('localhost', 'admin', 'XXXXX', 'admin_mySQL');
This code is on a php file which is hosted on my server.

I receive this feedback when I try to log in using the username and password I use to connect to the server through remote desktop:
   Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I receive this feedback when I try to log in using the username and password I have set up for database access in Plesk Panel:
   Invalid request

I am not sure if the problem is my user name and password or if I have set up something wrong or have the wrong settings on my server.
What can I do to check the problem and correct it?

Thanks

Comment: mysql's default install is to have a `root` account with no password.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with plesk, the first thing to ask is, have you created a user and database in the database control panel of your Plesk?

When you select a domain, you have a bunch of icons, in there you have "databases". Inside databases, you can create users at first if i'm not wrong, and then you create the databases, not sure tho, i haven't work with Horriplesk in a while ;)

Comment: I created a username and password through plesk and can connect to mysql through a client application, but when trying to connect with php I get an "invalid request" response and it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Then i really don't know what is the problem, maybe your hosting provider can help...